# Unity 3D： RPC buffer stop working when the initial player disconnects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am using Photon for networking with Unity. It's a peer-to-peer networking library. I basically have an RPC call to all targets (buffered) to change some game states.  But when the initial player disconnects, the future players cannot get the game state anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If RPC Buffer "belongs" to the Room, upon a player disconnection you should be fine. Either something is owned by that particular player or some object associated with disconnected players is still alive, ending up breaking the Loop.

Check [THIS](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/249255/how-do-you-remove-rpcs-from-the-rpc-buffer-that-wh.html) site, it might give you some answers.

Take into special consideration this part in his explanation:

```
void OnPlayerDisconnected(NetworkPlayer player)
```

Cheers